# View and Delete Users List Views

Tags: list-view, delete

We have recently removed the users rights to Edit/Create/Delete their own list view so that they will use the company shared list views.

This unfortunately had people trying to stab us because we took their permissions away as they can't edit their own list views.

So the question is how do I in mass or one by one delete users private list views? This can be either in the metadata or GUI.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you will have to delete them one by one. In the meanwhile you can upvote for the idea [Mass Delete Views (Clean up personal lists in one go)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrdJAAS)

After you remove this permission ***Create and Customize List Views***, Users will still have access to all of their previous List Views.

> However, a User's private List Views (those which haven't been shared
>   with other Users) will lose the ability to be edited or deleted, even
>   by users with the “Modify All Data” permission​.

So you will have to re-enable the permission and delete the private views first.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Is there a way to impersonate a user and delete their list view?

Comment: @Gunner1714 I'm not sure but you can try [Login as user](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=logging_in_as_another_user.htm&type=5)