# "This list API name is used by a public or private list view. Choose a different name" ListView

Tags: administration, list-view

We have a Existing List View in case object, and we have requriement to add a new filter to this existing list View - ( Subject> does not contain> xyz)
When i try to select this filter and when i click on save
It throws Error: "This list API name is used by a public or private list view. Choose a different name"

I have tried to rename Listview API but option is grayed Out - Please help

Answer (score 1):

The "List API Name" can be specified only at the time of creation via UI which is why you are seeing it greyed out.

As the error suggests, the reason behind it is that someone might have created a ListView with the same API name.

You can extract it with the Metadata API, update it and redeploy it. You might have to hunt down and delete the private list views manually as there isn't an API-driven way to do it (only supports Public listviews).

See [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239046/view-and-delete-users-list-views) and related [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddBvUAJ/mass-delete-custom-views)

Another way would be to use `Save As` after adding the filter which will have a unique API name.
[image]